# Apply central limit theorem with strict inequality

Tags: probability-theory, central-limit-theorem

Let $\{X_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ be an i.i.d sequence with mean $0$ and variance $1$. The CLT tells us that

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \mathbb{P}\left\{\frac{ \sum_{i=1}^nX_i}{\sqrt{n}} \leq x\right\} = \Phi(x)$$

where $\Phi(x), x \in \mathbb{R}$ denotes the probability distribution function of a standard normal variable.

Is it true that $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \mathbb{P}\left\{\frac{\sum_{i=1}^nX_i}{\sqrt{n}} < x\right\} = \Phi(x)$$

as well? (Note that I replaced the inequality by strict inequality).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, because $\Phi$ is continuous.  The set $B=(-\infty,x)$ is a *continuity set* for the Gaussian distribution so $P( S_n/\sqrt n \in B)$ tends to the Gaussian probability of $B$, that is, to $\Phi(x)$.  $B$ is a continuity set because its boundary $\partial B=\{x\}$ has Gaussian probability $0$.  In other words, because $\Phi$ is continuous at $x$.

Read all about it at the wikipedia articles on the [Portmanteau theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_measures#Weak_convergence_of_measures) and on [continuity sets.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuity_set)

Comment: Thanks! I'll check these things out!